# Running xp_cmdshell in SQL Server to run python script. Xlwings portion throws 'Access is denied' error

Tags: python, pywin32, sql-server-2017, xlwings, xp-cmdshell

I have been stuck with this for a while but if I get this right - nothing like it.
I am trying to run a python script from SQL Server using xp_cmdshell using the below code

```
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXEC xp_cmdshell '<PythonInstallationFolderPath>\python.exe "<.py FilePath>"'

EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 0
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

The above code works fine - it runs the python script (I can say that it runs because the python script saves some data from me in an excel sheet). In the python script, I have a code to do some formatting on the excel sheet:

```
import xlwings as xw
# create an excel instance app object as a context manager to make sure files are closed safely
app = xw.App(visible = True)
# open workbook
excel_book = app.books.open(fr'<ExcelFilePath>\Dummy_Name.xlsx')
# fetch active sheet 
ws = excel_book.sheets.active
# select Cell A1 and press Ctrl + A
tbl_range = ws.range("A1").expand('table')
# create table 
ws.api.ListObjects.Add(1, ws.api.Range(tbl_range.address))
# save and close workbook and app object
excel_book.save()
excel_book.close()
app.quit()
```

This code runs perfect when I run it from a Python IDE (like anaconda prompt or VSCode).
However, when I call the python script from SQL Server using the command xp_cmdshell as shown above, it fails with the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 80, in <module>
    app = xw.App(visible = False)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.impl = xlplatform.App(spec=spec, add_book=add_book)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 296, in __init__
    self._xl = COMRetryObjectWrapper(DispatchEx('Excel.Application'))
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 113, in DispatchEx
    dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, None, clsctx, serverInfo, (pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,))[0]
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)
```

I can with certainty say that the above error is associated with the xlwings section above. Thats because if I remove the xlwings section, the remaining code in my python script runs correctly.
From the traceback, I can understand that access is denied. Hence, I tried a few ideas like using xw.App(visible = False) instead of xw.App(visible = True) and trying to also run using context manager. But these dint work.
I am new to xlwings and also to shell commands. I found that this error has relation to pywin32 library from other stackoverflow question and answers like these:
[Win32com codes not working on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195793/win32com-codes-not-working-on-iis)
[ImportError: No module named win32com.client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23864234/importerror-no-module-named-win32com-client)

I presume xlwings library or xp_cmdshell does some sort of call to pywin32 library to perform the operations above.
I also found that this library is an advanced library for conversing with Windows which suggests to me that it will be difficult for me to debug. Hence, I am seeking your expert help.
I have been stuck with this for sometime now and would really appreciate a direction to explore towards or maybe help me pinpoint what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why use `xp_cmdshell` when SQL Server natively supports running Python?

Comment: I used machine learning services and found it to be a bit slow to run and also the error messages thrown were not so easy to debug. I found calling python scripts from sql agent job was a good way to run python scripts - yet we have been recently moving away from sql agent jobs because we started to have several jobs running together. Hence, finding an easy alternative to sql agent jobs.

Answer (score 0):

the traceback you mentioned above shows that it anaconda is being used to execute script. try using local python instead :

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 80, in 
> app = xw.App(visible = False)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 212, in **init**
> self.impl = xlplatform.App(spec=spec, add_book=add_book)   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlwings_xlwindows.py", line 296, in
> **init**
> self.*xl = COMRetryObjectWrapper(DispatchEx('Excel.Application'))   File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32com\client_*init**.py", line
> 113, in DispatchEx
> dispatch = pythoncom.CoCreateInstanceEx(clsid, None, clsctx, serverInfo, (pythoncom.IID_IDispatch,))[0] pywintypes.com_error:
> (-2147024891, 'Access is denied.', None, None)

Comment: win32api.FormatMessage(-2147024891) above returns the string 'Access is denied.\r\n'. and hence I am getting the error --> 'str' object has no attribute 'decode' <--. I am not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: the purpose was to get a comprehensive error.

Comment: also i noticed that you're using anaconda environment to run snippet. Try using python installed on your system which you most probably used in VsCode, Anaconda environment is notorious for access issues

Comment: I used both for your code above. Getting same error because e_msg is a string object.

Comment: NO no. ignore debugging script. try running YOUR script with local Python installed

Comment: I ran it with local python installed and it runs correctly. The error occurs only when I make a call to the script from SQL Server using xp_cmdshell.  (EXEC xp_cmdshell 'PythonFolderPath\python.exe "FilePath"')